# Flutter firebase Updating fields overwrites existing data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update the fields(AC for example) in the rooms using flutter....

[image: Firebase values]

The problem is it is overwriting the existing fields..like in the image below[image: Over writing picture]

Here is my code to update the field:

```
            _firestore.collection("UserData").document(email).updateData({
                        room: [
                          {title: statevalue}
                        ]
                      }).then((value) {});
```

What is that I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. So Thing is Firestore doesn't allow such operation. That is trying to update the value of a list. However you can update the value you wish to locally then update the firestorm value.

First, you'd fetch the data locally.

Then, update the value you wish to update

```
room[0]["AC"] = true;
```

Lastly, push back to firestore.

```
 _firestore.collection("UserData").document(email).updateData({
     room: room
  }).then((value) {
 // value updated
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't provide any operations to update individual items of a list field.  What you will have to do is.

1. Read the document
2. Modify the array in memory
3. Update the array field back to the document